# .login not called on CentOS Login

Tags: bash, variables, authentication, centos

as I read the bash shell should call /home/myUser/.login each time myUser logs in.
That is where I want to set and export some variables:

Within /home/myUser/.login:

```
.  /etc/login
... and some user specific variables later.
echo .login done.
```

Within /etc/login some common variable settings like:

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/home/ec2-user/sw/wildfly-8.2.0.Final
echo /etc/login done.
```

None of the both echos is displayed.
But

```
.  /home/myUser/.login
```

works.

drwx--x--x  6 myUser myUser  4096 Jan 15 18:42 myUser

Because in useradd -m ... the -m is ignored, 
and useradd -p hallo ... does not hash the password (but passwd --stdin  does),
I wonder if I am the one doing the mistakes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO!

The bash shell reads from several files during an interactive login session. `.login` is not one of them.

#### From the INVOCATION section of the bash man page

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The
>   `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, that helped immediately. Even when renaming  ~/.login  to  ~/.profile  (what I had tried) it still had been hidden by ~/.bash_profile that exists by default.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash` (RHEL 6 and RHEL 7):

```
  ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
```